# How to use Core Data with ODBC data sources?

Tags: sql, macos, cocoa, core-data, odbc

How can I use Core Data with ODBC data sources? I can see that Core Data can use SQLite. How about other relational databases? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Core Data certainly doesn't have any built in support for ODBC. However, it is possible to extend Core Data to use custom store types. So, in theory, you could write your own support for ODBC for Core Data. See Apple's documentation [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/AtomicStore_Concepts/Introduction/Introduction.html) for information on how to create a custom atomic store. [Here](http://nshipster.com/nsincrementalstore/) is information about a (relatively) new addition to Core Data that allows you to write custom support for incremental stores.